# JSON outputted as key with blank value

Tags: ios, json, node.js, hapi.js

So I have a dictionary that I'm trying to send to a Node Hapi server from an iOS device.

And for some reason my request payload is adding the dictionary as a key with a blank value.
Here is my iOS code

```
NSDictionary *userData = [User userToDictionary: newUserInfo];
NSData *userJSON = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: userData options: kNilOptions error: nil];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@/addNewUser", kBaseURL, kUsers];

// This will set up the URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// This will set up the url session
NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: config];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request fromData: userJSON completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
    {

    } else
    {

    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

And here is my payload

```
{ '{"userLastNameKey":"Kwon7","userEmailKey":"email7","userFirstNameKey":"Michael7","userUsernameKey":"username7","userPasswordKey":"password7"}': '' }
```

can anyone help me with this? I don't want to save my user information in mongo as a key. Just seems weird.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer, so I can finish answering your other question ;)

Comment: HAHAH I've spent like 6 hours on this hahah I've pull all my resources on both the IOS and the server side hahahaha still have a hard time solving it but you got me on the right track HAHA

Comment: I don't know iOS dev, but can you check it you're not serializing your JSON twice? it looks like you're making a json object, then encapsulating it into another object...

Comment: I debugged my iOS code and made sure of that hahaha it's either on the hapi side or the iOS side.

Comment: try printing userdata, and userjson, on the ios side, and show me how it looks

Comment: @xShirase - the site has a policy on piling tags into the title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/173448)

Comment: @jww as i wrote in my edit description : may be improvable, the question is weird and may depend on either Node/hapi or iOS... Feel free to edit if you've got better

Comment: @jww followed your suggestion based on the fact that you have 10x my rep. But I find this policy ambiguous to say the least, and apparently I'm not the only one. The question has a lot less meaning with the tags removed from the title

Comment: @ xShirase - I disagree too. I'm one of the dissenters in the post. But policy is policy...

Comment: Post the source for `-userToDictionary:` and log the value of `newUserInfo`. I have the feeling the answer lies in there.

Comment: No, I finally solve it. It seems that my header for some reason in my code wasn't going through I took another look at my code and I wasn't setting them right. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer even though the OP has solved his problem and explained what was wrong.  He said it was the headers.  I had the exact same problem and the solution was specifically the `Content-Type` header.  Since we were passing a JSON object into the REST client, we figured it took care of setting the right `Content-Type`, but it does not.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

HAPI will **not** assume the request payload is JSON.  A `JSON.stringify(request.payload, null, 2);` shows the same format as the problem in the question.  You must specify `Content-Type` for Hapi.js to correctly parse a JSON payload as JSON.